# Grouping i.e. () is not working properly

Tags: javascript, regex

```
"& Help is available in the Library, ".match(/(i)/)
```

This should be returning all the matches for "i". 
Instead it's returning only 2.

[image]

Two questions

1. It should be returning all the matches as that is suggested by mdn
2. What does index=7 mean in the array(in the picture)

For reference, Here is the definition that found on mdn

> (x)
>   Matches x and remembers the match. These are called capturing
>   groups.
>
> For example, /(foo)/ matches and remembers "foo" in "foo bar".
>
> The capturing groups are numbered according to the order of left
>   parentheses of capturing groups, starting from 1. The matched
>   substring can be recalled from the resulting array's elements [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm9SA.png),
>   ..., [n] or from the predefined RegExp object's properties $1, ...,
>   $9.
>
> Capturing groups have a performance penalty. If you don't need the
>   matched substring to be recalled, prefer non-capturing parentheses
>   (see below).

Comment: "This should be returning all the matches for 'i'" This assumption is incorrect. What led you to believe that this was the case?

Comment: Why do you think groups make your regex global? I don't understand what part of the MDN description makes you think it will match all instances of the group. If you clarify that, I might be able to give you a correct interpretation of whatever text there confused you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two are the full match and the submatch, which happen to be the same.

What you'll need is a global regex, by adding the `g` modifier.

```js
console.log("& Help is available in the Library, ".match(/i/g));
```

I also removed the subgroup since it's equal to the full match.